# How to disable servicehub.identityhost for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to install c++ templates on Visual Studio and it keeps showing this message which I can't solve.

[image: img]

Comment: It is trying to tell you to terminate Visual Studio (aka devenv).  Click the close button and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close all visual studio windows before installing updates or new features.

If you have closed them all wait for a while for them to stop running, then check for the processes in task manager. If all else fails restart your machine.